# Power Query Decimal values not loading

Tags: excel, powerquery

For a side exercise, I am trying to bring in the odds for sporting events into an excel sheet using Power Query. I am using the following link as a source: https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/

The event details import correctly, however, the odds are not being loaded.

I have tried changing the data type to text with no success.

I would expect a decimal value to be loaded for the Odds, such as 1.25 but instead, a dash is being imported.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior but do not have a solution.  For clarity, I'd suggest you edit your post to add a screenshots of the website, the PQ Editor, and the final result on your worksheet.

Comment: The page at that URL initially loads with dashes. The odds information that you want seems to be populated dynamically (via JavaScript). Sometimes you can identify the information being sent (maybe as JSON or something) in your browser's development tools (or using some network/traffic analyser). If so you, it might be possible to request just the data instead of the site page.

Comment: @chillin That is an interesting observation. But I don't understand why, when I load that information into PQ, the values under the `1|X|2|B` columns show up (as numbers or text), but not when the PQ is loaded back to the excel worksheet.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I just tried it and I was surprised to see any odds information load at all in Power Query (I had wrongly assumed something about the nature of Power Query up until now). For me, it loaded the odds information fine (both in the query editor and to the worksheet), but occasionally (say 1 of 10 refreshes) I get dashes. There is an `M` function `Web.BrowserContents` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-browsercontents) which might have been more appropriate to use here (as it allows a condition to be specified), but unfortunately it seems unavailable in Excel.

Comment: The documentation for `Web.BrowserContents` says *Specifies a condition to wait for before downloading the HTML, in addition to waiting for the page to load (which is always done)*. Maybe what's happening with `Web.Contents` (I'm assuming we're all using it) is that the HTML is being downloaded as soon as the document is ready -- and there is no guarantee at that precise moment if JavaScript on the page has replaced the dashes with odds information. I'm only assuming/guessing though.

Comment: I might be looking at the wrong thing, but the page appears to be periodically polling `https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament/1/h2NtrDMq/X0/1/?_=XXX` where `XXX` is a current Unix timestamp expressed in milliseconds. The JSON-like resource returned contains some readable keys like `oddsData`, but for the most part the names are obfuscated. Seems like some match `xeid` attributes in the HTML itself, so I presume that's how the JavaScript knows what table row the "odds information" relates to. Would probably need to pause and step through the JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: @chillin That's all well and good. I never see the actual odds (unless I examine the HTML itself).  I see values in the columns I mentioned above that are in the `100's range` looking at the PQ Editor, and these numbers never get carried onto the Excel worksheet.  Something going on I don't understand at all.

Comment: @chillin - can confirm that I also do bring in the odds approximately 1 in 10 times as well and your theory regarding Web.BrowserContents does seem valid - however, would that also not apply to the other fields - such as the match fixture or is it just the odds?

Comment: @RishabGoonoa I'm not familiar with the website but if by "match fixtures" you mean the dates,  times and teams/clubs (e.g. Liverpool - Newcastle), then I would say maybe there are (at least) two "groups" of information. The first group of information are things that will not change -- and maybe the dates, times, clubs/teams fall into this first group. The second group of information are things that will change e.g. the odds information. "Change" here means that the JavaScript may refresh odds periodically to ensure the user is always seeing up-to-date information.

Comment: @RishabGoonoa If you open your internet browser, temporarily disable JavaScript, then load the site you should see the initial HTML (before any JavaScript has run). My point is the other fields (like dates, times, clubs/teams) are present/static in the initial HTML returned. So to answer your question directly, it seems like it only applies to the odds.